# Lua - automatically turn - into -- if between two numbers

Tags: macros, lua

I've repeatedly read that Lua can do some cool under-the-hood things to TeX. One thing that comes to mind: I have a rather forgetful coworker who always used a hyphen instead of en-dash between two numbers, ie: `0-60` instead of `0--60`. I thought this would be a cool challenge (and selfishly good for my learning) to ask the following:

Could a Lua-based macro (or two) to enable/disable changing a - to -- if it is between two numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are two ways to interpret your request.

- You could be looking for a LaTeX macro that takes an argument and converts `-` to `--` if (and only if) `-` falls between two digits, as in `0-60`. In the code below, this LaTeX macro is called `\DashToEn`. The macro, in turn, calls a Lua function called `dash2en` to do the actual work.
- You could be looking for a preprocessor-type solution, which is supposed to act on (parts of) the input stream *before* TeX starts its usual work and converts all instances of `[digit]-[digit]` to `[digit]--[digit]`. In the code below, this approach is enabled and disabled via LaTeX macros called `\EndashOn` and `\EndashOff`, respectively. `\EndashOn` assigns a Lua function called `makeEn` to the LuaTeX `process_input_buffer` callback; conversely, `\EndashOff` removes this Lua function from the callback.
- Observe that the `dash2en` and `makeEn` functions differ only in the way they "return" the result of the `string.gsub` operation: `dash2en` passes the result to the `tex.sprint` function, whereas `makeEn` just places the result back into the input stream. (Recall that TeX's usual processing --  "eyes", "mouth", etc. -- isn't active yet when the `process_input_buffer` callback is doing its job.
- Finally, observe that the string `A-Z` is *not* converted to `A--Z` by `\DashToEn` or if `\EndashOn` has been invoked. This is, of course, exactly as it should be according to the OP's specifications.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment

%% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function dash2en ( s )
  s = s:gsub ( "(%d)%-(%d)" , "%1--%2" )
  tex.sprint ( s )
end
function makeEn ( s )
  s = s:gsub ( "(%d)%-(%d)" , "%1--%2" ) 
  return s
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

%% LaTeX-side code
\newcommand\DashToEn[1]{\directlua{dash2en("#1")}}
\newcommand\EndashOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback (
   "process_input_buffer" , makeEn, "makeEn" )}}
\newcommand\EndashOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback (
   "process_input_buffer" , "makeEn" )}}
  
\begin{document}

0-60 55-65 99-101 A-Z

\DashToEn{0-60 55-65 99-101 A-Z}

\EndashOn
0-60 55-65 99-101 A-Z

\EndashOff
0-60 55-65 99-101 A-Z

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very cool..didn't realize how easy it can be. cheers

Comment: There are a few situations where an en-dash between two digits is wrong: (a) in a url or doi; (b) in an ISBN or ISSN; (c) in an ISO-formatted date (2021-09-21); (d) in a "sectioned" page number -- although this is usually something like "A-1" or "II-1", the first element is sometimes just an ordinary Arabic digit.  So use with care.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I whole-heartedly agree with the "use with care" caveat. Speaking for myself, I interpreted the OP's write-up as looking for a proof-of-concept solution and not as something that would be put into action in an unsupervised manner.

Comment: Definitely--this is why asked for the ability to turn it off when needed. You are correct @Mico, this is more out of interest.

Comment: Still one caveat: a DOI and page numbers can very often occur in the same biblio entry, so more structure will be needed there than is usually provided by BibTeX formatting.  (Not sure about biblatex.  All I know is that I often shoot myself in the foot forgetting such details.)